# Hint: $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt[4]{x} - 12 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

this is my way:

$$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt[4]{x} - 12 = 0$$

$\sqrt[4]{x} = 12 - \sqrt{x}$
$x = (12-\sqrt{x})^4$

but I don't know how to simplify $(12-\sqrt{x})^4$

Comment: Hint: $t=\sqrt[4]{x}\to t^2=\sqrt{x}$ with $x\ge 0$

Comment: The "Hint" is actually your "question"?

Comment: yes i dont want exact answer

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

You can use $\sqrt[4]{x}=t$ and then your equation became:

$$t^2+t-12=0\to (t-3)(t+4)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

To solve
$$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt[4]{x} - 12 = 0$$
Set $\sqrt[4]{x}=p$ so $\sqrt{x}=p^2$

and the given equation becomes

$p^2+p-12=0\to p_1=-4;\;p_2=3$

reset $\sqrt[4]{x}=-4$ is impossible in $\mathbb{R}$

$\sqrt[4]{x}=3\to x=3^4=81$

so $\color{red}{x=81}$ is the unique solution of the equation

Answer (score 0):

after the hint above we get with $$t=\sqrt{x}$$ the following equation
$$t^4+t^2-12=0$$ with $$t^2=z$$ we get a quadratic equation
$$z^2+z-12=0$$
solving this we obtain
$$z_1=-4,z_2=3$$ can you finish?

Comment: yes thank you Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: @Sarvar "Thank you" for confusing $t$ and $t^2$? Well...